# Flutter: APT: error: 'description' is incompatible with attribute description (attr) reference

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

When starting the application I get an error that the description is incompatible with the attribute. Removing the attribute entirely does not solve the problem. What do I need to change?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.turn_off"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="android.app.Application"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="turn_off"
        android:testOnly="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.turn_off.MainActivity"
            ...
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.turn_off.DeviceAdmin"
            android:description="description"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/policies" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
         ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The receiver part can receive a description? I can't find it on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element

Comment: That's true but when I remove it the error stays. Even when I rebuild or invalidate caches and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuild the project from scratch and changed the receiver to:

```
<receiver
     android:name=".DeviceAdmin"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```